# Swift 2 how to get JSON value

Tags: json, swift

I have reached this stage so far

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers )  as! NSDictionary;

for item in json {
    print (item);
}
```

Output:

```
(firstitem, 1)

(seconditem, 'something else')
```

How do I get for example value of "`seconditem`"?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a dictionary, you can simply call it like a dictionary:

```
json["seconditem"]
```

If you want to keep your loop, you can loop through the key value pairs:

```
for (key, value) in json {
    print(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers )  as! NSDictionary;
        for item in json {
            print (item);
        }
        print(json["secondItem"]) //prints value for "secondItem" key
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("error: \(error)") // sth goes wrong, invalid json etc.
    }
```

You casted it to NSDictionary so you can access its objects like with normal dictionary: `json["key"]` or `json.valueForKey("key")`